# Predict based on time using a weibull

Tags: r, weibull-distribution

Example data with weibull decay for growth:

```
library(tidyverse)

# example weibull
example_df <- data.frame(
  day = 1:30,
  growth = dweibull(seq(1, 30, by = 1), shape = 0.1)
)

example_df |> ggplot(aes(x = day, y = growth)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Data looks like this:

```
example_df |> head()
  day      growth
1   1 0.036787944
2   2 0.018348802
3   3 0.012186100
4   4 0.009104847
5   5 0.007257658
6   6 0.006027639
```

Each day, growth decreases a little - a decay.

I would like to predict decay on a given day. Here's where I get confused.

Suppose I'm asked what decay is on day 20? Or day 25? How can I use a weibull regression to tell me? Tried something:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fit.weibull <- fitdist(example_df$growth, distr = "weibull", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0))

fit.weibull |> summary()
Fitting of the distribution ' weibull ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
         estimate Std. Error
shape 0.962954378         NA
scale 0.004707553         NA
Loglikelihood:  130.1494   AIC:  -256.2989   BIC:  -253.4965 
Correlation matrix:
[1] NA
```

This seems to fit a weibull curve to my data. But I also need to 'tell it' that growth is dependent on day.

I looked at survreg and survival packages but they want binary 1/0 data for survived/not survived. For my problem, I just want to associate day with growth using a weibull to be able to predict growth on a given day index.

How can I use a weibull to predict growth on a given day?

Comment: It is difficult to determine what your actual problem is because you seem to be confusing the formula for a Weibull density with a Weibull distribution.  Could you please tell us, *in non-technical terms,* what your data mean and what you are trying to learn about them?

Comment: Hi @whuber let me try here. We have an app and want to model revenue growth. Revenue grows by a decreasing amount each day, it looks similar to the plot I generated above. So, I would like to use a weibull regression model in order to predict growth on new installs. E.g. if 100 people install our app on monday and in total they spent $1K on day 1. How much revenue would they spend on day 2, day, 3, day 10, etc? Can I use a weibull in this way? Let me know if it's still unclear? I basically wnat to pass a data frame to a weibul regression with 2 fields: Growth Rate and Day

Comment: A graph that conforms to the formula for a Weibull density is *not* a Weibull regression model! You ought to back up quite a bit and consider what a reasonable form for the decay might be--exponential, power, something else.  Then, by considering how data might vary, you can provisionally select  a form of model that is suitable for their conditional variations.  That raises a lot of questions, but I doubt any of them would be correctly answered by making your software work.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to tell a weibull regression that growth is a function of day. You have answered other questions and pointed me elsewhere. Is it possible to use a weibull regression to model growth as a function of day?

Comment: You won't do it with `fitdist`! That's not performing a regression: it's estimating a (univariate) distribution function.  You need software to perform nonlinear regression; but what kind of nonlinear regression and which software will depend on the conditional distribution you assume for the model.

Comment: OK... in this case I want to try a weibull. My real data may or may not be weibulll shaped but it looks like it when I plot. Is there an r package that would let me pass a dataframe to fit a weibull where `growth ~ day`? The packages I did see use Surv objects which expect 0/1 event data. Rather than 0/1 event data I want to pass a vector that just shows a decreasing growth rate. Is there an R package out there for this>?

Comment: With some diffidence--because I suspect it isn't truly applicable for your data--I can refer you to the build-in [nls function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/nls).  Here on CV we have [many worked examples of nonlinear regression, with `R` code.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=nonlinear%20regression%20%5br%5d%20is%3aanswer%20score%3a2)

Comment: Could you show me how? Tried: `nls(GrowthRate ~ TENURE, data = .mydf, algorithm = 'weibull')` which errors with "'arg' should be one of “default”, “plinear”, “port”"
Note, it's fine if I'm 'wrong' with using a weibull. It's totally fine.

Comment: Also tried `nls(GrowthRate ~ SSweibull(TENURE, Asym, Drop, lrc, pwr), data = mydf)` but that gives error "singular gradient"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(day = 1:6, 
                     growth = c(0.036787944, 0.018348802, 0.0121861, 0.009104847, 0.007257658, 0.006027639)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

#fit the model
model<-nls(growth ~ a*exp(-b*day), data=df, 
    start=list(a=1, b=0.1))

#Set up the prediction
test <- data.frame(day=1:10)
test$y<-predict(model, test)

#Plot
plot(df$day, df$growth, ylim=c(0, 0.04), xlim=c(0, 10))
lines(test$day, test$y, col="blue")
```

Here we are using the simple exponential decay formula $growth = a*e^{-b*day}$.  If this fit is not satisfactory, then maybe try a polynomial or another function of your choosing.