# Decay function (e.g. weibull?) with numeric (i.e. not survival analysis) data

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, weibull-distribution

An example data frame:

```
exdf <- structure(list(TENURE = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 
59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 
75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 
91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 
73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 
89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100), GrowthRate = c(0.522068407541269, 
0.285714748576455, 0.185508515947955, 0.197014234790025, 0.0955682840302288, 
0.104550241818405, 0.0729165843177029, 0.052710172057008, 0.111205299930434, 
0.0842167291103291, 0.0435357167369297, 0.0342561790820088, 0.0697015114811705, 
0.0567551900498326, 0.0367956747574549, 0.0300708018467208, 0.0351762377682974, 
0.0355785502062602, 0.0212760525934605, 0.0363614825795171, 0.0283660359906612, 
0.0276822491674977, 0.0280297636181288, 0.0176973848620943, 0.0269962225046196, 
0.0232995719858735, 0.0132348057981257, 0.0231117576016402, 0.0200135248674158, 
0.0138992243554679, 0.0204646137008204, 0.0147834886226441, 0.0177097949074607, 
0.014717031805624, 0.0132285475095113, 0.0212633514283631, 0.00842835296173483, 
0.0145954105765114, 0.0101416096952409, 0.0134118780421613, 0.00938878674984167, 
0.0129743252759109, 0.0109985830231452, 0.0283401588275556, 0.0204205991521889, 
0.0093976137766294, 0.00910728837933128, 0.00916694752719849, 
0.00741753979164272, 0.00881249103330362, 0.0111578966749217, 
0.0192836374335688, 0.0120252563211682, 0.00586430387931181, 
0.0143027002879901, 0.00370704967795099, 0.00682983045111385, 
0.0141476105093492, 0.00482637041824496, 0.00420690319208639, 
0.00376569470107668, 0.0109937747749598, 0.0140867803731126, 
0.00371637851743323, 0.00717512598946612, 0.00768842197231479, 
0.00251049125312619, 0.00187703000356798, 0.0048259385225542, 
0.0100417595068638, 0.00374772165540982, 0.0171614859902469, 
0.0149367579256126, 0.0115188216576438, 0.00490666943969309, 
0.00530930735473234, 0.00723074299963677, 0.00592049387249816, 
0.00484467566849744, 0.0124063039986577, 0.00573257723329412, 
0.00427949785279758, 0.0030963281113916, 0.00252914919374447, 
0.00635090782429515, 0.00210452127168104, 0.00804075169058649, 
0.00436670408574535, 0.0035060879778257, 0.00713604840396798, 
0.0023981009089411, 0.00175704532860088, 0.000779919174233257, 
0.00340671636283396, 0.00460636923636137, 0.00120733393667471, 
0.00933279440430645, 0.00305741675516025, 0.00304857402624847, 
0.641110630691566, 0.281083708481502, 0.21664831342118, 0.142526508746734, 
0.129455004633227, 0.102003156382356, 0.0774235271374781, 0.0549670789691081, 
0.0809027507369802, 0.0460263351173751, 0.0653262071979981, 0.047154349769059, 
0.0385947285426713, 0.0430288757773969, 0.0406360525819185, 0.0430116335897406, 
0.0588492430703393, 0.0532880434533727, 0.0428311618518791, 0.0318427099482772, 
0.028791324553973, 0.023804027169529, 0.0201765096165349, 0.0333877840776626, 
0.02423781438746, 0.0209281238862644, 0.0152334901166924, 0.0206101546399822, 
0.0192309106927642, 0.0217159111858543, 0.0204661728941318, 0.0147045919062503, 
0.00963324607321603, 0.0168095825286532, 0.00772585884807775, 
0.0141943686223769, 0.0105122199425551, 0.00730692991230875, 
0.01505280063156, 0.00993250009012492, 0.0190685740493759, 0.0138696114197483, 
0.00991543096798608, 0.0140457461257082, 0.0238644668564838, 
0.014335212464454, 0.016231440976755, 0.0136006335528513, 0.010508195169141, 
0.0108223681012323, 0.00724634873393271, 0.0114878660557896, 
0.010768179227167, 0.0125569796266074, 0.00746257416521345, 0.00541761544241481, 
0.00915133561343495, 0.0128090265857459, 0.0128834975364693, 
0.00616011529066718, 0.0124072342143222, 0.00813729534453778, 
0.00918992619169501, 0.00776227156683262, 0.00770248250797501, 
0.00588355687767006, 0.00690140085420765, 0.00508911144051716, 
0.00911620445070582, 0.00830466702459098, 0.00520036975577831, 
0.00716886970824682, 0.00303064818576892, 0.0053193981576598, 
0.00327658374593653, 0.00321651271471524, 0.00513516303969652, 
0.00823984725674798, 0.00417642468764257, 0.014131171763804, 
0.00787422067561749, 0.00692890013640657, 0.0121753072926065, 
0.0070034266847312, 0.00540091988640867, 0.00689103254072876, 
0.00506455733404643, 0.00598304422775975, 0.00661625550389644, 
0.00732959383078224, 0.00720982160244255, 0.00564679063948148, 
0.00435863414775284, 0.00556842035294203, 0.00603506069392346, 
0.00548744139395829, 0.00660639356662429, 0.0045943028618467, 
0.00490921014265311, 0.713632131494036, 0.316109107238324, 0.19955189191854, 
0.149362726365638, 0.140527584352695, 0.122967115856381, 0.0629710542708235, 
0.0794423836726601, 0.0723283480042465, 0.048411305500041, 0.0878323397155594, 
0.0552740672330323, 0.0540408087274855, 0.0711265884999275, 0.0461176344041601, 
0.0421688829740532, 0.0408229960327535, 0.0337191263188075, 0.0365627089380531, 
0.0343486264915729, 0.0369672518324808, 0.0324027127903612, 0.0335280505737625, 
0.0241231062680551, 0.0315868501489174, 0.0260876281368159, 0.0358190565406051, 
0.031770274327048, 0.0307189115217597, 0.0204031908865456, 0.0304622366438121, 
0.0488170927658, 0.0395661396435187, 0.0234030909209384, 0.0225458543480528, 
0.0312754025113176, 0.0135110740643416, 0.0187184090181205, 0.013568316123143, 
0.0170345821576348, 0.0184100113763801, 0.019219623166352, 0.0137349197436514, 
0.0131633552715194, 0.0157758351970561, 0.0117732814253362, 0.0111181879788198, 
0.0193989282426799, 0.0121149862839278, 0.0136437991248339, 0.0111608014682734, 
0.011828405955594, 0.00944009280512503, 0.0123120446979428, 0.0175349768061963, 
0.0243703580512893, 0.00775361404112473, 0.0115755699642719, 
0.00869789602322868, 0.0230748185953917, 0.011388761136665, 0.0144514590777103, 
0.0114791528596783, 0.0121005997846328, 0.00959154057558642, 
0.0125793490404558, 0.0106768149670486, 0.00824512497201191, 
0.0076573705531775, 0.0104520640098951, 0.0115961878675463, 0.0132315972263175, 
0.00453620536761079, 0.00996315028677053, 0.00699906839894915, 
0.0100602309904119, 0.00881275005589721, 0.00840590467502622, 
0.00410243169790725, 0.00393864651260856, 0.0027632056756115, 
0.00604623344076316, 0.00644190206596029, 0.0073296018951492, 
0.0062144137386646, 0.00779570731803325, 0.00465780201362875, 
0.0141815826452891, 0.0121929551749531, 0.00573235434597308, 
0.00512844095153575, 0.0122186637666211, 0.00354975243105926, 
0.0158151971904505, 0.006405119131486, 0.00504244314036839, 0.00623419419033411, 
0.00664127009174464, 0.00428700468190435)), row.names = c(NA, 
-297L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's a plot of the data:

```
exdf |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = TENURE, y = GrowthRate)) +
  geom_point()
```

Looks like this:
[image]

I would like to model GrowthRate as a function of Tenure.

Just eyeballing the plot, I thought that maybe a Weibull regression would be appropriate. However, all I could find there was survival analysis where one passes a Surv() object to a regression and where the surv object contains 1/0 data for whether or not the observation has survived or not. i.e. binary data.

I'm being deliberately open ended here. What is a 'good' way to model the relationship between GrowthRate and Tenure (in R)?

Comment: Could you explain how this differs from your [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560512/predict-based-on-time-using-a-weibull)?

Comment: In several ways. First, I've provided actual, though disguised data (E.g. your comment over there "A graph that conforms to the formula for a Weibull density is not a Weibull regression model!"). Second, I've worded this in a way to be deliberately open ended. I've hinted towards weibull because I _think_ a weibull is appropriate, but I cannot see how to make it work with this data frame. Actually, I would have liked to delete that post and started fresh with this one but since someone already answered I did not close. But...

Comment: ... , Dave's answer... I struggled to read what was happening here. Is it a weibull? nls() syntax is 'hard'.

Comment: At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35717/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74594/919 I describe a simple, effective method.  It results quickly in `lm(GrowthRate^(1/3) ~ I(-TENURE^(-1/3)), exdf)` and you can go on from there. But parts of your post remain mysterious. I don't understand why you insist on some form of "Weibull regression," whatever that might mean.  And what does this have to do with survival analysis? There's no indication of right censoring.

Comment: Thanks for these links. "I don't understand why you insist on some form of "Weibull regression,". This is why I'm posting! I know "weibull regression" is a 'thing' because if I search that expression I get a lot of results. But, as far as I can tell they use 'weibull regression' in the context of survival analysis whereas I have a decay analysis...

Comment: If I image search 'weibul regression'I see some lines that look similar to the plot above, e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.xlstat.com%2Fs%2Farticle%2Fweibull-model-in-excel-tutorial%3Flanguage%3Den_US&psig=AOvVaw0u_nYU4ssAUj1Meyb6hmZo&ust=1642706868713000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCLDI_ozGvvUCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI) or [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fes.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDistribuci%25C3%25B3n_de_Weibull&psig=AOvVaw0u_nYU4ssAUj1Meyb6hmZo&ust=1642706868713000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCLDI_ozGvvUCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP)

Comment: That's why I'm 'clinging' to it!

Comment: All decreasing curved paths are going to look qualitatively similar: that appearance is no basis for choosing a functional form.  Your questions shouldn't be about weibull regression or weibull models or particular curves: they should be about understanding your data.  You don't seem to have any good reason to insist on the use of anything weibull for that purpose, so mentioning it looks more likely to misdirect readers than to guide them towards giving you good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doug, I saw your comment let take this one step at a time.

The Weibull probability distributions functions is
$ \frac{k}{\lambda} * (\frac{x}{\lambda})^{(k-1)}* e^{-(\frac{x}{\lambda})^k}$ for x greater than 0.  This is a 2 parameter model ($k and \lambda$) where we need to estimate the values for both k and lambda.  We have the x (ie tenure) and the dependent variable GrowthRate.

A the `nls()` nonlinear least squares function is a straight forward way to perform this fit.

This Weibull equation will translate into: `"GrowthRate ~ k/lam*((TENURE/lam)^(k-1))*exp(-(TENURE/lam)^k)"`

```
i<-15 #Extra parameter to scale
#Fit k and lambda in with Weibull probability density function
#initial estiamtes is k=1 and lambda=2
model_Weibull<-nls(GrowthRate ~ i*k/lam*((TENURE/lam)^(k-1))*exp(-(TENURE/lam)^k), data=exdf, 
                   start=list(k=1, lam=2))

#print summary of model
summary(model_Weibull)

#Now plot using base graphics
plot(exdf$TENURE, exdf$GrowthRate, xlim=c(1, 100))
test <- data.frame(TENURE=1:100)

#Now use the model to make the prediction
test$y<-predict(model_Weibull, test)
#Plot the prediction
lines(test$TENURE, test$y, col="green")

#Now use the model to make the prediction
test$y<-predict(model_Weibull, test)
#Plot the prediction
lines(test$TENURE, test$y, col="green")
```

#Repeat the fit with a different model

```
model<-nls(GrowthRate ~ a*exp(-b*TENURE), data=exdf, 
           start=list(a=1, b=0.1))
#print summary of model
summary(model)

#Set up the prediction
test <- data.frame(TENURE=1:100)
test$y<-predict(model, test)
#Plot
lines(test$TENURE, test$y, col="blue")
```

[image]

From the image the Weibull model is in green and a simpler exponential model $a *e^{-b*TENURE}$ is in blue.

Hope this explains how to perform a regression with R.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I personally find nls() tricky to follow but have been reading some tutorials on it lately

Comment: btw, copying from a tutorial I found, this basic fit did very well on the example data `nls(GrowthRate ~ I(TENURE^power), data = exdf, start = list(power = 1), trace = T)`

Comment: But really appreciate being shown how to use a weibull fit using nls, I half just wanted to know how to do it, regardless of how well it fits

Comment: Yes, it can be tricky, especially if you have the wrong model for the data or your initial estimates are way off.  The error messages from the function can be confusing and unhelpful.  Agreed, the "power fit" is another good option to try.

Comment: It is unreasonable to use a Weibull density (or any other density, for that matter) to fit a model like this, because it presuppose the data integrate to unity.  *At a minimum,* you need to allow for a vertical scaling of the Weibull density values.  When you do this, *the Weibull is an extension of the Exponential model* (corresponding to $k=1$).  Consequently, when this exercise is done right, *it is impossible for the Weibull fit to be any worse than the Exponential fit.* For these reasons I think your results are misleading and not useful.